# delete order/speed of std::lock_guard relative to other stack-allocated objects?

Tags: c++, multithreading, c++11, locking, mutex

As far as I can tell there is quite a bit of time between between the lock_guard getting deleted and when a function (run in another thread) actually returns. See the comment below in TEST(...)

```
bool bDone = false;
void  run_worker(Foo* f) {
  f->Compute();
  bDone = true;
}

TEST(FooTest,ThreadFoo) {
   Foo* f = makeFoo();
   std::thread  worker( run_worker, f );
   worker.detach();
   micro_wait(100); // wait for N microseconds

   f->Reset(); // should block until Compute() is done

   // !!?? Why is this necessary !?!? 
   int k=0;
   while(++k<500 && !bDone)
     micro_wait(100);**   

   EXPECT_TRUE(bDone); // Fails even with a single micro_wait(100)!     
}
```

Is there a good explanation for when/why there can be such a time lapse 
between when f->Compute() finishes and bDone gets set? My suspicion is that the mutex gets unlocked while there is still work to be done cleaning up stack-based variables allocated in Compute() but this is purely a hypothesis.

Stubs for Compute and Reset are below:

```
void Foo::Compute() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex>  guard(m_Mutex);
  // ... allocate bunch of temporary stuff on stack, update *this
}

void Foo::Reset() {
  std::lock_guard<std::mutex>  guard(m_Mutex);
  // ... simpler stuff, clear
}
```

Comment: This code looks very broken. There's no guarantee that `Compute` will acquire the lock before `Reset`. Also `bDone` is being accessed without synchronization. Enjoy your Undefined Behavior.

Comment: Right, this situation is better handled with std::future + std::async;    the first micro_wait(100) for the purpose of this experiment prevents Reset from getting the lock first. I am just asking for an explanation of how the very next statement of assigning a value to a bool variable after the Compute can fail to complete before Reset is done.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no synchronization of `bDone`.

It's quite possible that the compiler loads `bDone` into a register while it's value is false, and then continues to use the register cached version, instead of acquiring the updated version from memory. Alternatively, your instructions may be reordered such that `bDone` is set to false *after* the lock is released.

The correct way to approach this is to use an `std::atomic<bool>`. The worker thread can update it with a call to `bDone.store(true)` and the waiting thread can read it's most current value with a call to `bDone.load()`.

If you want to read into memory ordering to help understand why an atomic is needed, you can further improve this (though for a unit test, it really doesn't matter) by using `acquire` and `release` ordering.

Aside from this, what you really should be doing is joining your worker thread. A join blocks until the thread has ended, so you can be assured that your `Compute` function has completed execution. If you're afraid that it may run forever (or for too long), I'd suggest using `boost::thread` instead of `std::thread`, as it provides a `timed_join` function, which stops waiting for the thread after a specified period of time.

Comment: yeah replacing bool with atomic<bool> + removing worker.detach() + inserting worker.join just before the EXPECT_TRUE(bDone) leads to good behavior.